CMake Tutorial Step 4 TODO 4
I'm going through the CMake tutorial, and am completely new to it.
On Step4, TODO 4 we have the text:
# TODO 4: With nested generator expressions, only use the flags for the
# build-tree
# Hint: Use BUILD_INTERFACE

But I'm at a loss as what they are actually suggesting here.
I understand:

there are compiler flags for the project.
there is a build-tree.

So ultimately when the compiler runs for files in the build-tree we will see those compiler options, e.g. -Wall
But what are they talking about there being 'flags' being used outside the build-tree. Are these some other targets that use files outside the build-tree? And those other targets should NOT use the compiler flags?
The answer given doesn't really explain what's happening either. We have:
target_compile_options(tutorial_compiler_flags INTERFACE
  "$<${gcc_like_cxx}:$<BUILD_INTERFACE:-Wall;-Wextra;-Wshadow;-Wformat=2;-Wunused>>"
  "$<${msvc_cxx}:$<BUILD_INTERFACE:-W3>>"
)

If I look up the documentation for '$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>'
We have:

Content of ... when the property is exported using export(),
or when the target is used by another target in the
same buildsystem.
Expands to the empty string otherwise.

So I can guess that sometimes the generator 'BUILD_INTERFACE' returns an empty string, OR the configurations.
But to what purpose?
What are they trying to do here?
To quote the answer:

Consumers of our installed project should not inherit our warning
flags.

So, what would 'inherit' the flags? It get's build, and then installed, and you're done.
The 'install' target is another target. Are we just saying, rebuild without the warnings during install?
